# Deleting database and creating database with the same name issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, drop-database

I am using nodejs, Mongoose and mongodb database.

Sometimes I have seen that if I drop a database that included some collections inside it, when I run my node which makes some collections inside the database ( with the same name ), then the information that I want to save as a new entity does not show correctly.

I need to also mention when I drop the database in mongo db shell I also manually delete all the catch files inside c:/data/db ( default mongo db folder).

I checked the mongo documentation, sometimes it could make a problem if you make a database with the same name of the deleted database. Located at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.dropDatabase/#db.dropDatabase

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question. The document you have linked describe the solution:

> **Warning:** If you drop a database and create a new database with the same name, you must either restart all mongos instances, or use the flushRouterConfig command on all mongos instances before reading or writing to that database. This action ensures that the mongos instances refresh their metadata cache, including the location of the primary shard for the new database. Otherwise, the mongos may miss data on reads and may write data to a wrong shard.